# Symfony - Simple array and form

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I'm running Symfony 3.4 LTS.
Among my entities I get :

- UserEntity
- ProductEntity

In the ProductEntity :

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="experts", type="simple_array")
 */
private $experts;

/**
 * Set groupexperts
 *
 * @param array $groupexperts
 *
 * @return Product
 */
public function setGroupexperts($groupexperts)
{
    $this->groupexperts = $groupexperts;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get groupexperts
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getGroupexperts()
{
    return $this->groupexperts;
}
```

For example, the column `experts` in database could be [2,7,9] where #2, #7 and #9 and IDs of users considered as experts for the related product. In my ProductForm :

```
$builder->add('experts', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC')
        ->andWhere('u.active = 1')
    },
    'choice_label' => function($user) {
        return $user->getFirstname();
    }
));
```

I don't want to make a ManyToMany relationship because I don't want another SQL table.
The form displays well in the front-end and visitors can select one or several users in a  HTML list. BUT users #2, #7 and #9 **are not selected by default**.

The generated `select` list looks like fine with good ID:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">John</option>
    <option value="2">Matthew</option>
    <option value="3">Brad</option>
    <option value="4">Georges</option>
    <option value="5">Luke</option>
    ...
</select>
```

How to make the mapping between the users list (generated by the `createQueryBuilder()`) and the user IDs array stored in the database ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to configure the `choice_value` option to return entity id. The default choice value for EntityType is the entity object but you need only id.

```
'choice_value' => function (?UserEntity $user) {
    return $user ? $user->getId() : '';
},
```

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-value

Comment: Thx for the answer. The generated `select` is already returning the good ID of users. Moreover, I can't use the `choice_value` option (multiple errors). I updated my code in the original topic with the full source and more details.

Comment: PS: the probleme disapears if I set `multiple` = false and set only `2` for example in the database field. I don't understand why. Is the issue on the side of the entity getters/setters ? I updated original post with it.